# pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.11:2.1.13 Is there a more elegant way to declare the body?

Tags: jvm, pact

In pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.10 there was this:

```
DslPart part = PactDslJsonArray.arrayEachLike()
            .object("person")
            .integerType("id", 1)
            .stringType("pkey", "STU-12345")
            .stringType("firstname", "Billy")
            .stringType("lastname", "Joe")
            .stringType("grade", "01")
            .closeObject()
            .asBody()
            .array("organizations").object()
            .integerType("id", 1)
            .stringType("name", SCHOOL_NAME)
            .closeObject();
```

In pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.10 all I can find is this:

```
builder.uponReceiving("a request for Sections")
                .path("/api/1/sections")
                .method("GET")

                .willRespondWith()
                .headers(headers)
                .status(200)
                .body("[{\"value\":42}, {\"value\":100}]").toFragment();
```

Is there no longer an elegant way to define a JSON structure? I apologize, but I have looked all over and all I see are simple examples for 2.11.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: In Pact 2.10 there was the .arrayEachLike() method that allowed for elegant expression of the Json body. I see that is no longer in Pact 2.11, all the examples I see have the Json body explicitly coded in as a string. This is not do-able for large Json payloads. Can anyone point me at a way to elegantly code the expected Json payload using  Pact 2.11 jvm?

Comment: Thanks, pratibha, I am using https://github.com/mstine/microservices-pact as my base, but I see no elegant way to express complex json payloads, except in pact 2.10

Comment: Can anyone point me at any pact jvm 2.11 example that displays complex json payloads coded in a non-string format?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no, there isn't for the old DSL.  However, [you're in luck since we have a shiny new DSL which is much better in almost every way by using Java 8's Lambda feature](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-consumer-java8).  Hope that helps.  Cheers.

Comment: I just ended up using JSON and .toString(). Glad to know that was the way to go. I look forward to the shiny new DSL as I am implementing pact for my company

Comment: @CecilMcCecil The new DSL is ready, as long as you're using Java 8.  Just following the link I gave you.